# Powershell ForEach-Object output

Tags: powershell

More of a basic question but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. I am trying to go through a list and then output the Computer Name and BDE status with it.

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\Test\Test\IT\Lists\LaptopList.txt' | ForEach-Object { write-host "***" | manage-bde -status }
```

Is there something I need to put where the *'s are so that it correlates with the computer/object and the status?

Thanks!

Comment: The `"***"` would be `"$_"`, but that's only part of the problem - `Manage-BDE` needs to be run on each computer on your list. That command also returns multiple lines of output, so you'd need to parse out the relevant bits from it. The basic solution here is going to involve using `Invoke-Command` on for each computer in your list, running `Manage-BDE` and then parsing and returning only what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something I need to put where the *'s are so that it correlates with the computer/object and the status?

Yes! You're looking for `$_`:

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\Test\Test\IT\Lists\LaptopList.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host $_
}
```

As the name indicates, `Write-Host` writes output *directly to the **host** application* - in the case of `powershell.exe` it writes directly to the screen buffer - which means it doesn't *output* anything to downstream cmdlets in a pipeline statement like the one you've constructed.

You'll therefore want two separate statements:

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\Test\Test\IT\Lists\LaptopList.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host $_
    manage-bde -status
}
```

Now, `manage-bde` is *not* a PowerShell cmdlet - it's a windows executable, and it doesn't support managing remote computers.

So we need something in PowerShell that can run `manage-bde` on the remote machine - my choice would be `Invoke-Command`:

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\Test\Test\IT\Lists\LaptopList.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host "Remoting into $_ to fetch BitLocker Drive Encryption status
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { manage-bde -status }
}
```

Here, we instruct `Invoke-Command` to connect to the computer with whatever name is currently assigned to `$_`, and then execute `manage-bde -status` on the remote machine and return the resulting output, if any. Assuming that WinRM/PowerShellRemoting is configured on the remote machines, and the user executing this code locally is a domain account with local admin privileges on the remote computers, this will work as-is.

Further reading:

- [`about_Remote`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote)
- [`about_Remote_Requirements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements)
- [`about_Remote_Troubleshooting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting)

Comment: Since you have the list of machines up front why put it in a sequential loop? :-)

Comment: @DougMaurer To not distract from the primary question: how to refer to the current pipeline item :-)